# Translation between languages with different numbers of plurals

Tags: python, internationalization, gettext, python-babel

I am trying to create a translation file in simplified Chinese from an English source. This is all happening in a Flask project and I've been using Flask-Babel (so far successfully) to translate to Spanish and French. I added a Chinese translation file but I'm running into the following issue.

Consider the following strings in English:

```
msgid "One message"
msgid_plural "%(num)d messages"
```

When there is only one message, I don't want to display the number `1`, I want the spelled out version.

Apparenly, in Chinese, there is no grammatical difference between singular and plural, so our translators only included one translation for both versions:

```
msgstr[0] "%(num)d [something in Chinese]"
```

When I tried to compile this file, I got the following error message:

> unknown named placeholder 'num'

So I tried to duplicate the line like this (`一` is 1 in Chinese):

```
msgstr[0] "一 [something in Chinese]"
msgstr[1] "%(num)d [something in Chinese]"
```

But then I got this error:

> msg has more translations than num_plurals of catalog

which makes sense: Chinese has a `nplurals` of 1 so there shouldn't be more than one `msgstr`.

I see two options at this stage:

1. Cheat on my Chinese .po file and declare that `nplurals = 2` with the same rule as English: `"Plural-Forms: nplurals=2; plural=(n > 1)"`.
2. Update all my source strings so that I always use `%(num)d` in the singular version if I need it in the plural version.

I'm not really satisfied with either option. Is there an alternative?

Comment: Your first approach `msgstr[0] "%(num)d [something in Chinese]"` is correct and should work. Please post the entire po entry! Is there a `#, python-format` comment? And how exactly do you compile the po file? The regular GNU `msgfmt` has no problem with your example.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a bug in babel, not a problem of gettext.

The following PO excerpt is correct and compiles with `msgfmt --check`:

```
msgid ""
msgstr ""
...
"Language-Team: Chinese (simplified) <i18n-zh@googlegroups.com>\n"
"Language: zh_CN\n"
...
"Plural-Forms: nplurals=1; plural=0;\n"

#: example.c:1
#, python-format
msgid "One message"
msgid_plural "%(num)d messages"
msgstr[0] "%(num)d [something in Chinese]"
```

Until the bug is fixed, using option 1 (cheating on the plural-forms header) seems to be a viable workaround.  Or just use `msgfmt --check` instead of the Python script for compiling the po file.